# Cannot access my Server with ssl url

Tags: android, ssl, react-native, fetch

I am developing an iOS & Android Application with React Native. I use to access my backend server with "normal" url -> http:// ....

Now since i have changed it and added ssl i need to use my new backend url with ssl which is https://

On iOS everything works like it should. The problems are caused by my android app.

I am not sure how to solve this. Is there anything i have to do to access ssl based urls for android? Maybe in my Manifest or something? Any hints would be great...

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't want to trust server's certificate.
Which Android version you'd tested?
Older versions like 4.1.x haven't installed 'less known' CA's. 
Try it with Marshmallow.

To fix it you can always install a proper certificate on the device by hand (settings->security->load ca from sdcard) or change CA on the server to one which is more 'known' (probably more expensive).

BTW. Check out the logs. It should fail on SSl handshake.
Another test you can do is publishing a simple website by this server and try running this website over https on affected Android device. If the system doesn't trust it browser will alert you about that. For instance:
[image]